# Is it right to not read Quran because of being concerned about reading it wrong?

Tags: reading-quran

In countries whose native tongue isn't Arabic, some people, especially new learners, are afraid of reading Quran, because they might read it wrong. Is this understanding correct, or should they try to read it even if they might read it wrong?

Considering this ayah (73:4 - Sahih International);

[image]

> Or add to it, and recite the Qur'an with measured recitation.

One can conclude that this understanding is right. On the other hand, there might be special conditions for new learners.

Comment: In addition to my comment below - I recall one of my Islamic Studies teachers narrated a story, whereby a common villager did not know how to recite Quran. Everyday he would perform ablution, open the book and look at it, as if he were reading it. After a while he would close it. He did this for years. He said that Allah was so happy with this gesture (effort) that he gave him the ajr as if he had recited Quran. I do not know the origin of this story or have any more sources, but this fits well with the "Actions are judged by intentions". Rest, only Allah knows.

Comment: I don't think it's just a special condition. I think you're rewarded much more when you're just learning to read. I think this is the case because you have to exert more effort. Also, I think there is a hadith about this topic, but I can't seem to find it. I'll post it here if I do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not true, as in the [Hadith](http://sunnah.com/urn/182750) in Sahih Bukhari narrated by Aisha

> The Prophet said, "Such a person as recites the Qur'an and masters it by heart, will be with the noble righteous scribes (in Heaven). And such a person exerts himself to learn the Qur'an by heart, and recites it with great difficulty, will have a double reward."
>
> حَدَّثَنَا آدَمُ، حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، حَدَّثَنَا قَتَادَةُ، قَالَ
>   سَمِعْتُ زُرَارَةَ بْنَ أَوْفَى، يُحَدِّثُ عَنْ سَعْدِ بْنِ هِشَامٍ،
>   عَنْ عَائِشَةَ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ مَثَلُ
>   الَّذِي يَقْرَأُ الْقُرْآنَ وَهْوَ حَافِظٌ لَهُ مَعَ السَّفَرَةِ
>   الْكِرَامِ، وَمَثَلُ الَّذِي يَقْرَأُ الْقُرْآنَ وَهْوَ يَتَعَاهَدُهُ
>   وَهْوَ عَلَيْهِ شَدِيدٌ، فَلَهُ أَجْرَانِ

That means that everybody reading the Quran will be rewarded

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a great first answer -- I see you've picked up on our source-citing stuff already. Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

> innamal a'malu binniyat
>
> Actions are judged by intentions.

Good intentions get rewarded even if you do not do any action. Bad intentions are only penalized if you do bad intentions. (not directly related but useful to know)

If you attempt to read it and your niyyah (intention) is good, you will get the ajr (blessings). If you are worried about your pronounciation, take lessons and do the best you can.

Hazrat Bilal was an Ethiopian slave and his pronounciation of Azan was different from that of a native Arab, and yet our beloved Prophet PBUP liked his Azaan more than anyone else.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilal_ibn_Rabah_al-Habashi

> Later on, some people suggested that this honor should be given to someone else, because Bilal could not pronounce the Arabic letter 'sheen' properly and instead used the letter 'seen' (the two sounds had merged in "s" in classical Ge'ez). It is reported that Muhammad said, "The 'seen' of Bilal is 'sheen' in the hearing of God," meaning that God does not see the physical manifestation; He appreciates the purity of heart. This saying of Muhammad is held to be contentious by scholars of hadith, with almost all of them grading it as baseless.[5] Bilal felt deep love for Muhammad, and he is quoted as reciting some lines of poetry in his own language, in praise of Muhammad. One verse translated:
> "When noble traits are described in our country, thou art pointed out as a model among us."

Comment: Please source your answers properly. Especially hadith.